# Consulta de múltiplos dados MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

estou fazendo um chat e tenho a seguinte tabela no banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero listar as 5 últimas conversas de um usuário, mas a consulta é bem complexa, estou a um tempo tentando resolver com subqueries, mas não cheguei a nada, ela deve atender os seguintes requisitos:

- O usuário em questão pode ser tanto um remetente (`sender_id`) como um destinatário (`recipient_id`), então tem que buscar os dois, e quanto o usuário for `sender_id`, o `recipient_id` tem que receber um `alias` para ser um `user_id` (Veja o código adiante);
- Os resultados devem estar ordenados em `DESC`;
- Deve retornar a última mensagem da conversa;
- A mensagem não pode estar deletada para o usuário em questão (usei como boolean 0 para não e 1 para sim).

Os códigos:

-Onde listo as mensagens:

```
<?php foreach($list_messages as $msg) : ?>
        <?php $recipient = find_user($con, $msg['user_id']); ?>
        <a href="#" onclick="openPanelChat(<?php echo $recipient['user_id'] ?>)" class="dropdown-notification-content" style="background-color: <?php echo ($msg['seen'] == 0) ? 'rgba(28,146,243,0.08)' : 'white' ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $recipient['picture'] ?>">
            <b><?php echo $recipient['name'] ?></b>
            <p><?php echo base64_decode($msg['msg']) ?></p>
            <span><?php echo translateDateFull($msg['registry']); ?></span>
        </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

-A função que lista e retorna tudo em uma array

```
function list_messages($con, $user_id){
    $list_sql = "Essa é a consulta que quero!";
    $r = mysqli_query($con, $list_sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    $messages = array();
    while($each = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
        $messages[] = $each;
    }
    return $messages;
}
```

Exemplo de como fica uma conversa entre id=27 e id=31. Isso é uma conversa, vamos supor que esse id=27 seja eu "Artur" e o 31 seja "Vitória", quero exibir a ultima mensagem da nossa conversa, mas eu (id=27) posso ser tanto sender_id quanto recipient_id:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Bom, é isso, o resultado deveria ser algo parecido com o do facebook!

Comment: você poderia colocar um exemplo de como é a tabela com dados e como teria que ficar, isso melhora a interpretação!

Comment: Tá melhor agora?

Comment: É meio complexo, consegue ajudar?

Comment: `select * from tabela where (sender_id=27 or recipient_id=27) ORDER BY registry desc LIMIT 1` não só isso ?

Comment: Não, tem que retornar o id=37 como `user_id`, e tem que ser as últimas 5 conversas (não mensagens).

Comment: Consegui finalmente associar o usuário ao sender_id ou ao recipient_id, mas deve vir de forma distinta (sem duplices), considerando que independente do número de mensagens que você enviar ou receber, é apenas uma conversa. Tentei usando a cláusula DISTINCT (`SELECT DISTINCT IF(sender_id = 27, recipient_id, sender_id) as user_id, msg, registry, seen FROM messages_chat WHERE recipient_id = 27 OR sender_id = 27 ORDER BY id DESC limit 5`) sem êxito porque preciso de várias colunas (tentei usar subconsultas, mas piorou mais)...

Comment: Outra solução era usar o GROUP BY (`SELECT IF(sender_id = 27, recipient_id, sender_id) as user_id, msg, registry, seen FROM messages_chat WHERE recipient_id = 27 OR sender_id = 27 GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY id DESC limit 5`), mas o principal problema é que ele não ordena na ordem que estou especificando, justamente porque o GROUP BY faz seu trabalho primeiro.

Comment: Com `Group By` ele traz as 5 mensagens corretamente?

Comment: Ele traz 3 (que é o tanto que existe). O problema é que ele traz e só depois que executa o ORDER BY (de acordo com os resultados do GROUP BY). Ele traz os id distintos como é para ser, mas não traz na ordem!

Comment: Meu amigo é simples colocar a ordem então! 

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT IF(sender_id = 27, recipient_id, sender_id) as user_id, msg, registry, seen FROM messages_chat WHERE recipient_id = 27 OR sender_id = 27 GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY id DESC limit 5) AS tabela2 ORDER BY CAMPO_DE_ORDENAÇÃO`

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu. Na consulta que eu mandei (que vc colocou na subquery) retorna agrupado em ordem aleatória, quanto o ORDER BY vem logo em seguida, ele funciona em cima dessa ordem aleatória, o que não ajuda. O que eu quero é fazer igual o do Facebook, você tem conta? Ele pega as últimas mensagens e depois agrupa. Até tentei fazer isso: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT IF(sender_id = 27, recipient_id, sender_id) as user_id, msg, registry, seen FROM messages_chat WHERE recipient_id = 27 OR sender_id = 27 ORDER BY id DESC) AS tabela GROUP BY user_id limit 5`, mas continua em ordem aleatória.

Comment: http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/553073-multiplos-dados-na-consulta/#entry2207201

Comment: Motta, aqui desenvolveu bastante, o que você enviou lá não condiz muito bem com o problema, pode ajudar aqui?

Comment: Não consegui resolver ainda!